# Point2D ArrayList printing method in front of Coordinates

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, coordinates

I'm trying make a Point2D ArrayList of Coordinates, and then printing out to the user which coordinates are above the line y=x, below the line y=x, and on the line y=x. I think I have it, but for some reason whenever I print out my Point2D arraylist, it prints like this:

```
[Point2D.Float[1.0, 2.0], Point2D.Float[3.0, 4.0]]
```

How do I remove the Point2D.Float?

Here is my code:

Main.java:

```
package com.lucas.q1;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<Coordinate> coords = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
        ArrayList<Float> xvals = new ArrayList<Float>();
        ArrayList<Float> yvals = new ArrayList<Float>();
        ArrayList<Point2D> coordTest = new ArrayList<Point2D>();

        //ArrayList<Float> sortedList = new ArrayList<Float>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        float xinput;
        float yinput;
        Coordinate x;
        Coordinate y;
        boolean tst = true;
        while (tst)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter X: ");
            xinput = in.nextFloat();
            if (xinput == 000)
            {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Enter Y: ");
            yinput = in.nextFloat();
            if (yinput == 000)
            {
                break;
            }
            Point2D p = new Point2D.Float(xinput, yinput);
            coordTest.add(p);           
        }

        CompareCoords c = new CompareCoords(coordTest);
        System.out.println(c.printAboveLine()); 
    }
}
```

CompareCoords.java:

```
package com.lucas.q1;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class CompareCoords {

    ArrayList<Point2D> onLine = new ArrayList<Point2D>();
    ArrayList<Point2D> belowLine = new ArrayList<Point2D>();
    ArrayList<Point2D> aboveLine = new ArrayList<Point2D>();

    public CompareCoords(List<Point2D> coordTest)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < coordTest.size(); i++)
        {
            if (coordTest.get(i).getX() == coordTest.get(i).getY())
            {
                onLine.add(coordTest.get(i));
            }

            if (coordTest.get(i).getX() < coordTest.get(i).getY())
            {
                aboveLine.add(coordTest.get(i));
            }

            if (coordTest.get(i).getX() > coordTest.get(i).getY())
            {
                belowLine.add(coordTest.get(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(aboveLine.get(0));
    }


    public ArrayList<Point2D> printAboveLine()
    {
        return aboveLine;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a possible solution you can implement method `void printPoints(List<Point2D> points)` that prints list of Point2D objects to console. It could look like this

```
void printPoints(List<Point2D> points) {
   for(Point2D p:points) {
      System.out.println("[" + p.getX() + ", " + p.getY() + "]");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the `toString` method to the object you are printing and after that a `replaceAll` will do the job:

```
System.out.println(aboveLine.get(0).toString().replaceAll("Point2D\\.Float", ""));
```

Of course could create your own class `extends` `Point2D` and `@Override` `toString` method, but I am not sure if its worth it.